# How to get my name on the side of the Google search results?

Tags: google, search, name

For example http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=tom+brady&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#q=tom+hanks&rls=en

I have seen this on famous and non famous people and I was wondering how to get this done so my name and picture will appear on the sidebar of the Google search results.

Do I need to make an account or send Google a request?

Answer (score 1):

```
how to get this done so my name and picture will appear on the sidebar of the Google search results.
```

In order to get your name and image on Google search results you need your own Google Plus profile accounts with your name and image (using **[Google Authorship](http://blog.kissmetrics.com/google-authorship/)**) but you are asking the way to show your image and name in Google sidebar.  Your name will display only if Google considered you as a famous person with an article about you in Wikipedia. Google would show the details of a person from his/her Wikipedia article and Wikipedia will allow an article about a person if it finds a reliable reference source about that person.  So in order to show your details (Name and Image) in Google sidebar you must be a famous person.  In your example you have shown famous persons that’s why Google showing their details in the sidebar of its search result.

Comment: @David I participated in a question related to this earlier.  Its called the [Knowledge Graph](http://www.google.com/insidesearch/features/search/knowledge.html)

Comment: Noticed this question hit the stream since it was recently protected. Just wanna let ya know that authorship is no longer functional. Google removed that feature from their search result listings.